# Ubuntu lightdm.service does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

Not able to login Ubuntu from GUI but console is fine. Then I tried

```
systemctl start lightdm
```

It shows

```
Unit lightdm.service not found.
```

After reinstalling lightdm, got same result: lightdm.service not found

Ubuntu I'm using should be the newest version which I downloaded yesterday.(Oct30/2018)

Not sure what's going wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed: lightdm fails. And I'm using LXDE on Arch Linux for ARMv7 (different distro, different architecture). So it seems to be an upstream issue with lightdm, or a conflict with other upgraded packages (i.e., running Linux 4.19), I don't know, but it doesn't seem to be a distro specific issue.
`extra/lightdm 1:1.28.0-1 [installed]
    A lightweight display manager`

`lxdm` works fine. I suggest using that. Also, you might want to try `systemctl enable lightdm` instead of `start`. Using `start` crashed my Xorg server immediately, but `enable` gave me a seemingly fine message, but then failed to load on startup.

I actually found your question because one of my installation scripts didn't work:
    `systemctl enable lightdm.service`

I quickly realized that I didn't have lightdm installed on this system at the time and intended to use lxdm anyway. Funny, I thought I was using lxdm all along. so I changed it to:
    `systemctl enable lxdm.service` which works fine.

Here is some extra info for the record:

```
systemctl status lightdm
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-10-31 18:37:08 PDT; 13min ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
 Main PID: 259 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 31 18:37:08 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
```

Comment: issue posted with lightdm developers: https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/lightdm/issues/46#issue-376227121

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but not exactly the same: I thought that running

```sh
$ systemctl status lightdm
Unit ligthdm.service could not be found.
```

should work, even though I wasn't a root user or using `sudo`.
In that, I was mistaken.
Apparently, all calls to `systemctl` must be made with `root` permissions.
Both of the following commands worked.

```sh
# systemctl status ligthdm
$ sudo systemctl status ligthdm
```

worked.